# Why is an integer variable not accepted as a value for START WITH in sequence

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-sequence

I am trying to create dynamic start number for sequence but it is not accepting variable viz. `@START_SEQ`  for `START WITH`. Please consider following code : -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  [dbo].[SP_RESET_SEQ]
AS
DECLARE @START_SEQ INT =0;

BEGIN
SET @START_SEQ = (SELECT MAX(USER_ID)+1 FROM MASTER_USER);
IF OBJECT_ID('SEQ_USER_ID') IS NOT NULL
DROP SEQUENCE [dbo].[SEQ_USER_ID]

CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[SEQ_USER_ID] 
 AS [bigint]
 START WITH @START_SEQ
 INCREMENT BY 1
 MINVALUE 1
 MAXVALUE 99999999
 CACHE 
END
```

Comment: Looks like the `FROM` keyword is missing in your inner query

Comment: I did correction in my question. @Raj

Comment: What happens if a new user is added to `MASTER_USER` between reading the `MAX(USER_ID)` value and creating the sequence?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do the same with dynamic SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  [dbo].[SP_RESET_SEQ]
AS
DECLARE @START_SEQ INT =0;

BEGIN
SET @START_SEQ = (SELECT MAX(USER_ID)+1 FROM MASTER_USER);
IF OBJECT_ID('SEQ_USER_ID') IS NOT NULL
DROP SEQUENCE [dbo].[SEQ_USER_ID]

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sql = 'CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[SEQ_USER_ID] 
 AS [bigint]
 START WITH ' + @START_SEQ
 + 'INCREMENT BY 1
 MINVALUE 1
 MAXVALUE 99999999
 CACHE'

 EXEC(@sql) 
END
```

As noted by [ta.speot.is](https://stackoverflow.com/users/242520/ta-speot-is) below (thanks!), the syntax for `CREATE SEQUENCE` takes a constant (see [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx)).

Comment: I believe this is the only way to do it: [the syntax for `START WITH` takes a `<constant>`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx).

Comment: Works well except variable @sql. I had to convert @START_SQL into nvarchar `SET @sql = 'CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[SEQ_USER_ID] 
 AS [bigint]
 START WITH ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), @START_SEQ)
 + 'INCREMENT BY 1
 MINVALUE 1
 MAXVALUE 99999999
 CACHE`

Answer (score 4):

Another example as the above one not working with me

```
declare @maxBookingId as int 
select @maxBookingId = max(bookingid) from booking
declare @s nvarchar(4000);
set @s = N'
CREATE SEQUENCE Invoice_Seq  AS INTEGER  
START WITH ' + cast(@maxBookingId as nvarchar) + '
INCREMENT BY 1  
NO CYCLE;'

EXEC (@s);
```

Comment: `@maxBookingId + 1` ?

Comment: No sequence itself make the incremental operation :)

Comment: Oh right, normally the code that uses the sequence would use a NEXT VALUE. So it's fine if that sequence starts with the current maximum id.

Answer (score 0):

AS INTEGER in create sequence is not necessary

```
declare @maxBookingId as int 
select @maxBookingId = max(bookingid) from booking
declare @s nvarchar(4000);
set @s = N'
CREATE SEQUENCE Invoice_Seq 
START WITH ' + cast(@maxBookingId as nvarchar) + '
INCREMENT BY 1  
NO CYCLE;'
EXEC (@s);
```

This script is perfect to integrate in incremental distribution